# What is the best way to detect mouse / keyboard activity from windows service?

Tags: windows-services

I have a windows service that needs to perform some actions on "user activity" (mouse move, keyboard clicks) and on "user inactivity" (no mouse move / keyboard clicks for some time). Since service is in different session and computer can be locked / no user logged in, i can't use hooks, `GetLastInputInfo()`, `GetAsyncKeyState()` etc. Where are lots of advanced methods to interact with sessions from service, but maybe it's some easy solution exists that i can code fast in C / C++?

Comment: Google "session 0 isolation" to find out why you can't make this work.

Comment: I can make this work. But enumerating all sessions and spawning satellite processes in them and then communicating back seems like overkill. I'm just looking for a simpler solution.

Comment: If you need information from each session, you need code running there. Rather than the enum suggested in your comment, it's usually just done by having something in the startup folder.

Comment: Unfortunately, "startup folder" only works if user is already logged in to the computer. For example, if user is not yet logged in service will work but no items from startup folder will run.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to detect events from the secure desktop (which runs the login prompt until someone logs in)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Spawning a process in secure desktop session works just fine. Unfortunately, it's a lot of code and lots of special cases for different versions of Windows and different architectures. So i was hoping some easy way exist :).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, just for the record: I have implemented this via starting process in each session manually. Lots of code :(. But works :).